# AutoReg in statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels, finance, autoregressive-models

I am the AutoReg model in statsmodels

I am getting some very off results on my predictions which is making me think I am doing something incorrectly.

I am using teslas shareprice form yahoo finance:

```
ticker = yf.Ticker("TSLA")
observed = ticker.history(period="1d", start="2014-01-01",end="2022-03-01")["Close"]
training_data = np.log(observed['2014-01-01':'2021-01-01'])

tesla_model= AutoReg(training_data, lags=3).fit()

predictions=tesla_model.model.predict(tesla_model.params, start=len(training_data), end= len(training_data)+len(test_data)-1)
```

The results are shown in the table below. Predicted in using another function, more manual and AutoReg Predictions is using the predictions obtained through the above code.

[image]

If someone can shed some light as to why there are vastly different results or what I am doing incorrectly that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did exponentiate the predictions as the training data was the log